# Appending and handling duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df with timeseries data. Now I want to add more data, which I do by using DataFrame.append(). The data that will be appended **contains new columns and duplicate values**. Therefore, I clean up by removing duplicate values after appending. Is there a better way?

It works quite well, currently, but I am afraid of a duplicate search on lager DataFrames.

**This is an example df:**

```
              2022    2023    2024    2025
2021-02-15  17.029  16.286  15.525  15.510
2021-02-12  17.160  16.300  15.633  15.574
2021-02-11  17.089  16.316  15.733  15.630
2021-02-10  17.425  16.525  15.925  15.770
```

**This is the data to append:**

```
data = {}

for day in days:
    data[day] = {
       day.year+1: float(some_data1), 
       day.year+2: float(some_data2),
       day.year+3: float(some_data3),
       day.year+4: float(some_data4)
       }

appending_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

df = df.append(appending_df)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Pandas module in python provides us with some in-built functions such as dataframe.duplicated() to find duplicate values and dataframe.drop_duplicates() to drop duplicate values.

```py
dataframe.drop_duplicates(subset = ‘column_name’, keep =  {‘last’, ‘first’, ‘false’}, inplace = {‘True’, ‘False’})
```

> Dataframe : Name of the dataframe for which we have to find duplicate values.

> Subset : Name of the specific column or label based on which duplicate values have to be found.

> Keep : While finding duplicate values, which occurrence of the value has to be marked as duplicate. That is, the first value is to be considered duplicated or the subsequent values have to be considered as duplicate or all the values (false) have to be considered duplicate.

https://www.educba.com/pandas-find-duplicates/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, but I am already using drop_duplicates(). I would like to find a solution that will work with larger frames and more performance, like replacing data on a .loc and not inserting & dropping.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do is with groupby:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index).last()
```

This will keep the last row with the repeated index. If you want to keep the first row with the repeated index, simply:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

Comment: Doesn't groupby return a groupby-object instead of a DataFrame?

Comment: It does if you don't apply a function at the end. You and apply wether function suits your problem: mean(), max(), ...., last() or first(). In any case, the result is a DataFrame.

In my example, the resulting df is a DataFrame, as you can see:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html

Comment: Ahhhh, thats neat. Do you have any information about performance? Is groupby more efficient than drop_duplicates()? I had hoped to find a way to handle duplicates while inserting the data, but append() seems to be the way to go.

Comment: :) I actually don't know what is the best performing one. I did a quick search and cannot find information about it. Maybe you could test both ways for larger DataFrames?

On another hand, maybe you could speed up the execution if you condense both commands in the same command:

df = df.append(appending_df).groupby(df.index).first()

or

df = df.append(appending_df).drop_duplicates()